# Normalize Russian characters in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of russian regions and cities like this.

```
    >df                                                                                                                                                    
    russian_region
1          <U+0421><U+0432><U+0435><U+0440><U+0434><U+043B><U+043E><U+0432><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+043E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0430><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C>
2                                  <U+0421><U+0430><U+043C><U+0430><U+0440><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+043E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0430><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C>
3                          <U+0420><U+043E><U+0441><U+0442><U+043E><U+0432><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+043E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0430><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C>
4                                                                                           <U+0422><U+0430><U+0442><U+0430><U+0440><U+0441><U+0442><U+0430><U+043D>
5  <U+0412><U+043E><U+043B><U+0433><U+043E><U+0433><U+0440><U+0430><U+0434><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+043E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0430><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C>
6                                                                                           <U+0422><U+0430><U+0442><U+0430><U+0440><U+0441><U+0442><U+0430><U+043D>
7  <U+041D><U+0438><U+0436><U+0435><U+0433><U+043E><U+0440><U+043E><U+0434><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+043E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0430><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C>
8                                                                  <U+041F><U+0435><U+0440><U+043C><U+0441><U+043A><U+0438><U+0439> <U+043A><U+0440><U+0430><U+0439>
9          <U+041E><U+0440><U+0435><U+043D><U+0431><U+0443><U+0440><U+0433><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+043E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0430><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C>
10 <U+041D><U+0438><U+0436><U+0435><U+0433><U+043E><U+0440><U+043E><U+0434><U+0441><U+043A><U+0430><U+044F> <U+043E><U+0431><U+043B><U+0430><U+0441><U+0442><U+044C>
                                                                                                                russian_city
1                           <U+0415><U+043A><U+0430><U+0442><U+0435><U+0440><U+0438><U+043D><U+0431><U+0443><U+0440><U+0433>
2                                                                           <U+0421><U+0430><U+043C><U+0430><U+0440><U+0430>
3                         <U+0420><U+043E><U+0441><U+0442><U+043E><U+0432>-<U+043D><U+0430>-<U+0414><U+043E><U+043D><U+0443>
4  <U+041D><U+0430><U+0431><U+0435><U+0440><U+0435><U+0436><U+043D><U+044B><U+0435> <U+0427><U+0435><U+043B><U+043D><U+044B>
5                                                   <U+0412><U+043E><U+043B><U+0433><U+043E><U+0433><U+0440><U+0430><U+0434>
6                                                   <U+0427><U+0438><U+0441><U+0442><U+043E><U+043F><U+043E><U+043B><U+044C>
7          <U+041D><U+0438><U+0436><U+043D><U+0438><U+0439> <U+041D><U+043E><U+0432><U+0433><U+043E><U+0440><U+043E><U+0434>
8                                                                                   <U+041F><U+0435><U+0440><U+043C><U+044C>
9                                                           <U+041E><U+0440><U+0435><U+043D><U+0431><U+0443><U+0440><U+0433>
10         <U+041D><U+0438><U+0436><U+043D><U+0438><U+0439> <U+041D><U+043E><U+0432><U+0433><U+043E><U+0440><U+043E><U+0434>
```

I dont know why I get to see the UTF-8 characters as above, whereas when I do

> df$russian_city

, I get to see the names in Russian

```
> df$russian_region
 [1] "Свердловская область"  "Самарская область"     "Ростовская область"    "Татарстан"             "Волгоградская область" "Татарстан"             "Нижегородская область" "Пермский край"        
 [9] "Оренбургская область"  "Нижегородская область"
```

Is there something wrong with my environment settings that my R session cant read the Russian characters, and how do I handle it?

Comment: Are you on Windows?  R on Windows is known to mis-handle UTF-8 strings, because you are really unlikely to be working in a UTF-8 locale.  In any case, you should put together a reproducible example so others can see how you got where you are.  For example, `russian_region <-  "Свердловская область"; df <- data.frame(russian_region)`.  When I do that on MacOS I don't see any error.

Comment: Yeah, I am using Windows. When I use my work laptop which has a Unix system, I dont get the same error. As for the reproducible example, I downloaded the data set "train.csv.zip" from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/avito-demand-prediction/data and then read it using `read_csv  train <- read_csv("./train.csv",locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))`. The data frame `df` was just an example

Answer (score 0):

I had a ton of problems loading the database as well. I tried the methods used in [this notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/ambarish/very-extensive-analysis-and-xgb-avito) and that one didn't work as well. So I gave up and just changed the locale to Russian and everything works now. If other answers don't work, try this one.

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Russian")
```